# Storing files between requests in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using django sessions to store values between requests by using `request.session[key] = value` and retrieving them by `foo = request.session[key]`. Similarly I would like to store files and retrieve them between requests. Can someone please suggest me a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is never recommended to store entire file in session as the size of the file might make the session very heavy thus reducing the response time of your page.

I will suggest that you can write the file to a temporary location and maintain the path of the file in session and use that file path to access the files in any request.